# Meteor: How to use handlebars within handlebars

Tags: javascript, meteor, handlebars.js

I would like to use to refer to another template within an {{#each}} loop

html:

```
{{#each listOfItems}}
 {{>{{variableOne}}}}
{{/each}}
```

which should render

```
<Template name="one">
 One
</Template>
```

or

```
<Template name="two">
 Two
</Template>
```

depending on the js

other tried syntax include

```
{{>'{{variableOne}}'}}
```

or

```
{{>Template.dynamic template={{variableOne}}}}
```

Any help or workaround greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what are you trying to accomplish. I'm assuming you are using Blaze rendering engine. If you want to pass parameters try this:

```
{{#each}}
  {{> TemplateName variable=variable}}
{{/each}}
```

Or if you want to show certain template depending on variable value try this (watch out - eq is meant as global helper for comparing values):

```
{{#each}}
  {{#if variable eq 1}}
    {{> TemplateOne}}
  {{else}}
    {{> TemplateTwo}}
  {{/if}} 
{{/each}}
```

Comment: hm, I want one attribute of the documents from the each loop to define the template that is being loaded. So I dont want to define 'variable' in its own helper, it should be defined in the helper for the each loop

Comment: {{#each item in listOfItems}}
      {{#if item.property eq 1}}
        {{>TemplateOne}}
      {{else}}
        {{>TemplateTwo}}
      {{/if}} 
    {{/each}}

Check out this package with some useful helpers: [link](https://atmospherejs.com/universe/utilities-blaze)

Comment: this is what I was looking for. Have never seen the {{#each item in listOfItems}} syntax. But that would mean, I could do {{>item.templateName}}, right? Will try this out later :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the list you iterate over contains the template names, this will get you what you want:

html:

```
<template name="hello">
  {{#each template in myTemplates}}
    {{> Template.dynamic template=template }}
  {{/each}}
</template>

<template name='foo'>foo-template</template>
<template name='bar'>bar-template</template>
```

js:

```
Template.hello.helpers({
  myTemplates() {
    return ['foo', 'bar'];
  },
});
```